# Char arrays and if statement syntax

Tags: c++, c, optimization, arduino

I have problem with char array and if statement.

i try to do:

```
void Motors::manualMotion(int CycleDutyAzim,int CycleDutyPitch,char directionAzim[],char directionPitch[]){


    setCycleDutyA(CycleDutyAzim);
    setCycleDutyP(CycleDutyPitch);

    if(directionAzim=="FORW"){
        moveForwAzim();
    }else if(directionAzim=="BACK"){
        moveBackAzim();
    }else{
        Serial.println("FAIL");
        handbreakAzim();
    }

    if(directionPitch=="FORW"){
        moveForwPitch();
    }else if(directionPitch=="BACK"){
        moveBackPitch();
    }else{
        Serial.println("FAILED");
        handbreakPitch();
    }
}
```

I get all the time the serial.prints with the messages. I made it work with on char not an array. What is the syntax in order to work properly.When i call the method i give this:

```
Motors::manualMotion(90,50,"FORW","BACK");
```

It does not work.When i use one char like F and B, it works properly.

Comment: i also used instead of " " the ' '

Comment: `C` or `C++`, not both. Please choose!

Answer (score 4):

```
if (directionPitch == "FORW")
```

You cannot use `==` to compare strings.

When you pass an array to a function it decays as a pointer to its first element. When you use `==` for comparison, it only compares the address of the pointer with that of the string literal "FORW". This is obviously not what you want to do. What you want is comparison of the string literal with the content pointed by the pointer.

You need `strcmp` if you need to compare c-style strings.

On another note, why use `char []` instead of `std::string` in C++ anyways? It saves you all the problems of manual memory management and you can simply use `==` for string object comparison.

Comment: erm no, you can't use `strcpy`!

Comment: @Nim: It was obviously a typo.

Answer (score 4):

Because you can not compare C-style strings by `==` you should use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp).

However *arduino* hasn't STLs, but [there is a port](http://andybrown.me.uk/wk/2011/01/15/the-standard-template-library-stl-for-avr-with-c-streams/), then you can enjoy STLs. Another way is to use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of C-style strings.

```
void Motors::manualMotion(int CycleDutyAzim,int CycleDutyPitch,
const std::string &directionAzim, const std::string &directionPitch) { // ...
```

Comment: The Arduino compiler (avr-gcc) doesn't (as shipped) have any of the STL available to it.

Comment: @MatthewMurdoch: Yes, you are right, but there're some effort to port STLs [here](http://andybrown.me.uk/wk/2011/01/15/the-standard-template-library-stl-for-avr-with-c-streams/).

Answer (score 1):

C/C++ `char * ==` doesn't do what you think, use `strcmp/stricmp/strncmp` etc. instead. Don't worry, common mistake, especially if you're used to languages with inherent string types.

Also, you might consider enumeration types instead of passing strings.

Answer (score 0):

`if (variable == value)` can only be used to compare simple types, a character, an integer. 
An array of characters is NOT a simple type so you need a function to do the comparing. `strcmp` or `stricmp` will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you compare C-style strings, you should use `strcmp()` or similar.  When you do

```
directionAzim=="FORW"
```

You are comparing *pointers*.

```
char directionAzim[]
```

in your prototype could also be written as:

```
char *directionAzim
```

and `"FORW"` is of type `const char *`.  So, if you are passing:

```
Motors::manualMotion(90,50,"FORW","BACK");
```

that is *unsafe*, since there is nothing to stop the function from attempting to alter the literal (which will probably crash your program).  Your prototype should look something like this:

```
void Motors::manualMotion(int CycleDutyAzim,int CycleDutyPitch,
   const char directionAzim[], const char directionPitch[]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using string comparisons. Array comparison doesn't exist in that manner. C++ isn't going to do a null-terminated string comparison just because a `char` array *typically* is a null-terminated string. `char[]` won't get special treatment in this matter any more than `int[]` would.

Either use a string class like [std::string](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) or use [strcmp](http://cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/).